# exec() method invocations of Faker library in for loop | Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, exec, faker

Using **Faker** library; I am simulating a dataset, in Jupyter Notebooks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

import random

np.random.seed(42)


def example_dataset_simulation(samples):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(samples))
    
    df['ID'] = [str(i) for i in range(1, samples+1)]
    df['Prefix'] = [fake.prefix_male() for _ in range(samples)]
    df['Forename'] = [fake.first_name_male() for _ in range(samples)]
    df['Surname'] = [fake.last_name_nonbinary() for _ in range(samples)]
    
    return df


df = example_dataset_simulation(500)
df
```

Output of which is successful. Producing a unique dataset each time.

Now, I want to be able to alter the function to add **n** number of columns, as a variable integer passed named `cols`.

---

Desired for loop code:

```
list = [["Prefix", "fake.prefix_male()"], ["Forename", "fake.first_name_male()"], ["Surname", "fake.last_name_nonbinary()"], ["Suffix", "fake.suffix_male()"], ["DOB", "fake.date()"], ["e-mail", "fake.company_email()"], ["Telephone", "fake.phone_number()"]]

def example_dataset_simulation(samples, cols):
   df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(samples))
   
   df['Prefix'] = [fake.prefix_male() for _ in range(samples)]  # once
   
   for col_name, method in list[:cols-1]:
       df[str(col_name)] = [eval(method) for _ in range(samples)]  # cols-1
   
   return df
```

Output:

```
500 rows × 3 columns
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `exec` here at all

Comment: And you almost certainly meant `"fake.prefix_male()"` instead of `fake.prefix_male()`... but again, *don't use `exec` here to begin with* and in any case, `exec` returns `None`

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Will try `Faker` methods as `string` first to see if `exec()` works with it. If not then I'll remove `exec()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated the bottom-half solution in my post

Comment: `exec` won't work here, you'd need to use `eval`, **but you shouldn't use either**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, `eval()` worked for me! Why should I not use either?

Comment: Instead of `list = [["Prefix", "fake.prefix_male()"]...` do `list = [["Prefix", fake.prefix_male] ...` and then in the for loop instead of `eval(method)` do `method()`. PS try not to call variables `list`, that is the name of a builtin type.

Comment: If you have to use strings, then you can remove the "fake" from each string and remove the paranthesis at the end, like `list = [["Prefix", "prefix_male"]...]` and then in the for loop replace `eval(method)` with `getattr(fake, method)()`

Comment: That's maybe best, using `getattr()`. Will try it too. Thanks everyone

Comment: because it is hackey and generally not a good way to design your code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fair. I'll read into `eval()` and see what it's really used for, as well as these others. Thanks again.

Comment: The way I would do this is to put the method object in the list itself, so `["Prefix", fake.prefix_male]` then in the loop, use `df[str(col_name)] = [method() for _ in range(samples)]`

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` does exactly what I want.

```
list = [["Prefix", "fake.prefix_male()"], ["Forename", "fake.first_name_male()"], ["Surname", "fake.last_name_nonbinary()"], ["Suffix", "fake.suffix_male()"], ["DOB", "fake.date()"], ["e-mail", "fake.company_email()"], ["Telephone", "fake.phone_number()"]]

def example_dataset_simulation(samples, cols):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(samples))
    
    df['Prefix'] = [fake.prefix_male() for _ in range(samples)]  # once
    
    for col_name, method in list[:cols]:
        df[str(col_name)] = [eval(method) for _ in range(samples)]  # cols-1
    
    return df
```

```
df = example_dataset_simulation(500, 6)
df
>>> 500 rows × 6 columns
```